# Uploading .apk file in emulator

Tags: android, eclipse

i have a problem on uploading the apk file into emulator. it says...

```
[2013-11-26 12:34:30 - EMSProject] Installing EMSProject.apk...
[2013-11-26 12:34:44 - EMSProject] Success!
[2013-11-26 12:34:44 - EMSProject] \EMSProject\bin\EMSProject.apk installed on device
[2013-11-26 12:34:44 - EMSProject] Done!
```

..............
but my machine is not connected with any device. previously it was connected. but i removed the device from my system. i closed and reopend the eclipse ,i changed the emulator also, but nothing works.. still getting this line....

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the Run Configurations if you have selected any default device or emulator

Comment: try right-clicking the project and Goto->Android Tools->Fix project properties